# What's the conception behind: Type - Element - Mirror

Tags: java, annotations

I'm working with Java 6's annotation processing, i.e. what can be found within `javax.annotation.processing` (not Java 5's APT).

I wonder what the conceptional difference between the various `Element`, `Type`, and `Mirror` classes is. As I don't really understand this, it's hard to efficiently program an annotation processor. There are various methods that 'convert' between these notions but I'm not really sure what I'm doing when using them.

So, for example, let me have an instance of `AnnotationMirror`.
When I call `getAnnotationType()` I get an instance of `DeclaredType` (which implements `TypeMirror` for whatever reason).
Then I can call `asElement()` on this one and obtain an instance of `Element`.
What has happened?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The object of type `javax.lang.model.element.AnnotationMirror` represents an annotation in your code.

The declared type represents the annotation class.

Its element is the generic class (see http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/TypeElement.html for more information on that matter). The element might be the generic version of a class, like `List`, where as the declared type is the parametrized version, for instance `List<String>`. However I'm not sure it is possible to have annotations classes use generics and thus the distinction might be irrelevant in that context.

For instance lets say you have the following JUnit4 method:

```
@Test(expected = MyException.class)
public void myTest() {  
     // do some tests on some class...
}
```

The AnnotationMirror represents `@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)`. The declared type is the `org.junit.Test` class. The element is more or less the same as there are no generics involved.

Comment: The javadoc is not really clear about what the TypeElement is. I think it is more tied to the declaration of the type (thus the type parameters) while the TypeDeclaration (confusing name) is more tied to the use of the type like, for example, in a variable declaration. I get the idea that these two terms are hard to understand in the context of annotations.

Comment: But as per this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245638/understanding-typeelement-and-declaredtype-interface-in-java), `DeclareType` must be `MyException.class`

Answer (score 29):

There is indeed on overlap between these concepts.

- `Element` models the static structure of the program, ie packages, classes, methods and variables. Just think of all you see in the package explorer of Eclipse.
- `Type` models the statically defined type constraints of the program, ie types, generic type parameters, generic type wildcards. Just think of everything that is part of Java's type declarations.
- `Mirror` is an alternative concept to reflection by Gilad Bracha and Dave Ungar initially developed for Self, a prototype-based Smalltalk dialect. The basic idea is to separate queries about the structure of code (and also runtime manipulation of the structure, alas not available in Java) from the domain objects. So to query an object about its methods, instead of calling `#getClass` you would ask the system for a mirror through which you can see the reflection of the object. Thanks to that separation you can also mirror on classes that are not loaded (as is the case during annotation processing) or even classes in a remote image. For example V8 (Google's Javascript engine) uses mirrors for debugging Javascript code that runs in another object space.

Comment: Understanding this point  "you can also mirror on classes that are not loaded (as is the case during annotation processing" really helped me to work with Annotation processor.

Answer (score 7):

This paper may help understanding the design of Java 6 annotation processing:

> Gilad Bracha and David Ungar. [Mirrors:
>   Design Principles for Meta-level
>   Facilities of Object-Oriented
>   Programming Languages.](http://www.bracha.org/mirrors.pdf)  In  Proc. of
>   the ACM Conf. on Object-Oriented
>   Programming, Systems, Languages and
>   Applications, October 2004.

Comment: So, Instead of reflection api's like `getClass` in traditional reflection system, Do we have mirror based refection api's? `java.lang.model.element.AnnotationMirror` is something like `ClassMirror` (as mentioned in this paper)?