# Understanding 'TypeElement' and 'DeclaredType' interface in java

Tags: java, interface, annotations, java-8

One usage of these two interface, is to write annotation processor.

As a java beginner, I find  the level of indirection that is added by these two packages:
`javax.lang.model.element` & `javax.lang.model.type` to provide metadata about java `interface` and java `class` confusing.

[image]
.........

[image]

java doc comments say,

> `TypeElement` represents a `class` or `interface` program element. Provides access to information about the type and its members. Note that an `enum`
>   type is a kind of class and an annotation type is a kind of `interface`.
>
> `DeclaredType` represents a declared type, either a `class` type or an `interface` type. This includes parameterized types such as `java.util.Set<String>` as well as raw types.

Difference between the two:

> While a `TypeElement` represents a `class` or `interface` *element*, a `DeclaredType` represents a `class` or `interface` *type*, the latter being a use (or *invocation*) of the former.

How do I differentiate the jargon *element* from *type*? For example: How is `class` *element* different from `class` *type*? Please help me with an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *elements* are the parts that you use to compose a software, i.e. `ExecutableElement`s which, as the name suggests, contain executable code, `VariableElement`s which describe a kind of storage and `TypeElement`s which hold these together. It’s a special property of the Java programming language (as an object oriented language) that there are no top-level functions nor global variables without a `TypeElement`, in which they are defined.

In other words, if you write a Java program, you will always have at least one `.java` source file containing at least one type declaration. That `TypeElement` will likely contain at least one `ExecutableElement` to make up a useful software. The `TypeElement` may contain multiple `ExecutableElement`s, `VariableElement`s and nested `TypeElement`s. That’s the *structure* of your program.

---

A *type* is something which you use whenever you declare a member or local variable, but also when declaring a super class or -interface. But let’s focus on variables, for a better understanding:

A variable can have a primitive type, which is intrinsic to the programming language, it can also have a type whose existence is implied, e.g. when there is a type `X`, you can also use the array type `X[]` in a variable declaration, but only the *declared type* is a type which must have a corresponding `TypeElement`, representing something, a developer has written (or has been generated by a tool). Generics also allow you to compose types, e.g. declare a variable of type `Set<? extends Number>` whereas `Set` and `Number` are *declared types* which have corresponding program elements…

Comment: For your point: "declared type is a type which must have a corresponding TypeElement, representing something", If we take this [example](https://github.com/shamhub/Java_programming/blob/master/JavaCode/src/Dummy.java),  how do you differentiate TypeElement type and DeclaredType type for `class X`?

Comment: I don’t get your question. Why should I try to differentiate between two things which are just different views to the same thing? The important point is that the *Type* role can be fulfilled by entities which are *not* Elements, i.e. `int` and `void`, and the *Element* role can be fulfilled by things not being a declared type, like the variables `i`, `j` and `args` or the methods `m1`, `m2` and `main` in your example. It seems you are focusing too much on the intersection of these two concepts instead of the difference. And then you ask to find the difference within the intersection…

Comment: OK. So, you mean,  `m1`, `m2` & `main` have `ExecutableElement` type role. `i`, `j` and `args` have `VariableElement` type role. `X` has `TypeElement` role.  `int`, `void` have `PrimitiveType` role. Am  I correct? What is `DeclaredType` type role in my example?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I differentiate the jargon element from type? For example: How is class element different from class type? Please help me with an example.

You can think of the `DeclaredType` (type) as the generic type of a class (e.g. `List<String>`); compared to `TypeElement` (element) which essentially ignores the generic type (e.g. `List`).

---

You can start with elements, and build up generic types:

```
// Utility elements that come with javax.annotation.processing
Elements elements = processingEnv.getElementUtils();
Types types = processingEnv.getTypeUtils();

// These are elements, they never have generic types associated
TypeElement listElement = elements.getTypeElement(List.class.getName());
TypeElement strElement  = elements.getTypeElement(String.class.getName());

// Build a Type: List<String>
DeclaredType listStrType = types.getDeclaredType(
                               listElement, 
                               strElement.asType());

// Build a Type: List<List<String>>
DeclaredType listlistStrType = types.getDeclaredType(
                               listElement,
                               listElement.asType(),
                               listStrType);
```

Answer (score 0):

So first of all I must admit I am no Java Guru, but found your question interesting and spent some time learning about it. Here's what I found out.

In my opinion the whole concept is hugely connected with generics. As mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2127320/4250114

`TypeElement` is a statically defined type e.g `List<E>`, `List<? extends SomeType>`. Whereas `DeclaredType` is a concrete one like `List<String>`.

Some extra insight about the concept gave me the javadoc of `Types#getDeclaredType` method:

> Returns the type corresponding to a type element and
>   actual type arguments.
>   Given the type element for {@code Set} and the type mirror
>   for {@code String},
>   for example, this method may be used to get the
>   parameterized type {@code Set}.

As mentioned in another answer in the cited question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2127266/4250114) if you want to learn some more the paper of Gilad Bracha and David Ungar should be a good place(at least I am going to ;) ).

Of course you could also experiment on your own. E.g I have written such Processor that I was examining with debugger:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes({"annotationProcessor.MyAnnotation"})
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
public class AnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
        super.init(processingEnv);
        final Map.Entry<TypeElement, DeclaredType> collection = getType("java.util.Collection");
        final Map.Entry<TypeElement, DeclaredType> string = getType("java.util.String");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
                           RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        return false;
    }


    private Types typeUtils() {
        return processingEnv.getTypeUtils();
    }

    private Map.Entry<TypeElement, DeclaredType> getType(String className) {
        TypeElement typeElement = processingEnv.getElementUtils().getTypeElement(className);
        DeclaredType declaredType = typeUtils().getDeclaredType(typeElement);
        return new HashMap.SimpleEntry<>(typeElement, declaredType);
    }
}
```

Hope it helped...

Comment: Please go thru the new diagram, what is the difference between `TypeElement` and `DeclaredType` as per this new diagram?

Comment: The same. As you can see the TypElement `public @interface CompanionClass { Class<?> friend() }` represents whole "family" of types due to the '?'. One of the declared type is `public @interface CompanionClass{Class<Bar> friend()}`. As for `AnnotationValue`, it is `class Bar` so in this case TypeElement = DeclaredType, cause there are no placeholders.

Comment: Sorry, How do you differentiate `TypeElement` and `DeclaredType` in this [example](https://github.com/shamhub/Java_programming/blob/master/JavaCode/src/Dummy.java) for `class X`?

Comment: For this class they result in same construct `TypElement` and `DeclaredType` are both just `class X`, but they represent different layers of logic.

Comment: different layers of logic? I did not get you